# How do you check the order of a set of actions, given ranks for each of them?

Tags: r

I have this dataframe.

```
user    action    date        rank
AAA     jump      2018-01-01  1
AAA     climb     2018-01-02  2
AAA     leap      2018-01-03  3
BBB     jump      2018-01-01  1
BBB     climb     2018-01-03  2
BBB     leap      2018-01-05  3
BBB     gallop    2018-01-08  4
CCC     leap      2018-01-01  1
CCC     climb     2018-01-02  2
CCC     gallop    2018-01-04  3
```

It takes the actions and adds a rank per user according to the date, in ascending order.

I want to locate any users who took actions in the wrong order. The order should be `jump -> climb -> leap -> gallop`.

The output would be `CCC` since that user did leap before climb.

```
user   
CCC
```

How do you make a reference to a particular row? I am using `dplyr` and I can group it by each user and add the rank for each user, with `row_number()`, but I don't know how to make rules that check whether the actions are happening in the correct order.

Note - I realized this was unclear. Not every user takes all the actions, but the order still matters.

This is what I have working so far

```
badData <- NULL
for (i in df$user){
  filtered <- filter(df, user == i)

  first <- ifelse(filtered[filtered$action == "jump",]$rank > 1, TRUE, FALSE)
  second <- ifelse(filtered[filtered$action == "climb",]$rank < filtered[filtered$action == "jump",]$rank, TRUE, FALSE)
  #and so on for the rest of the rules

  if(first + second > 0) badData <- c(badData, i)   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `action` a factor and use the `levels` argument to set the order, you can group by user, then test if the actions are unsorted using `is.unsorted`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(action = factor(action, levels = c("jump", "climb", "leap", "gallop"))) %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  filter(is.unsorted(action)) %>%
  pull(user) %>%
  unique

[1] "CCC"
```

Comment: That's freaking radical. Really cool stuff, haven't seen that before.

Comment: Sorry, I pulled back 'accepted answer' because not every user has all of the actions. Some users might just have jump and gallop, but the order still matters. I should've mentioned that.

Comment: OK - this will still work even if the action set is incomplete.  Or do you want to flag those who don't have the correct order or have an incomplete action set?

Comment: You're right, this still works. So, `is.unsorted()` doesn't mind if there are values it doesn't have, it just makes sure that the values it does have are in the right order?

Comment: Also - this is a small style thing, is there a reason you chose unique instead of `distinct()`

Comment: Last question - `pull()`, is that like using `[[]]` to grab a column? eg, it grabs a column as a vector from a data frame?

Comment: Yes, `pull()` does exactly that.  This is also why I used `unique()` instead of `distinct()` as `distinct()` doesn't work on vectors.

Comment: If you're specifying an order explicitly, I'd use `ordered` not `factor`. I'm actually surprised `is.unsorted` works in this case given that `<` `>` `min` `max` etc won't work with a standard factor.

Comment: @thelatemail - I wondered if somebody would ping me over that.  You're probably right but I assumed its being coerced to an integer behind the scenes in which case it wouldn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example you can achieve this.
You first create a refrence dataframe  (`refdata`) which contains the correct order.
Then you can easily work with the `tidyverse` package:

```
mydata <- tibble(id = rep(c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), each = 4), action = letters[c(1:4, 1,2 ,4, 3, 4,1,2,3)],
       date = rep(1:3, 4)) 

refdata <- tibble(action = letters[1:4], right_order = 1:4)


mydata %>% left_join(refdata, by = "action") %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(test = identical(right_order, sort(right_order)))
```